# how to fix error Requested output format 'concat' is not a suitable output format

Tags: ffmpeg

This is my command

```
ffmpeg -f concat safe 0 -i C:\_source\mergethis.txt -c copy C:\_combined\combined.mp4
```

I get this error

```
[NULL @ 00000000022a5060] Requested output format 'concat' is not a suitable output format
safe: Invalid argument
```

mergethis.txt contains this

```
file C:\\_source\\01.mp4
file C:\\_source\\02.mp4
file C:\\_source\\03.mp4
file C:\\_source\\04.mp4
file C:\\_source\\05.mp4
file C:\\_source\\06.mp4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo. Change `safe` to `-safe`.

Comment: Nice catch! i'm ashamed to admit but been struggling for that the whole day.

Comment: @Wayne Nothing to be ashamed of. I'm sure most of us have spent way too much time on an issue due to one character being wrong or missing.